# ( probably ) A segment tree application

Tags: algorithm

I’ve though about this for a couple hours but I’m unable to make much headway. It goes like this :

> You have an array of size n and q queries. Each query is of the form
>   (l, r, k). The answer to each query is the index (1-based) of the
>   leftmost number in the range [l, r] which is greater than or equal to
>   k. If there is no such value, return -1.  Constraints: n, q <= 1e5, l
>   <= r and the elements can be from 0 to 1e9. The program should run
>   within a second.
>
> Example input :
>
> ```
> n = 5, q = 2
> 7 4 6 9 
> Queries :
> 3 4 7 
> 2 4 5
> Output:
> 4
> 3
> ```

I feel like a maximum segment tree might work here, but I am unable to put it together. Please help. Obviously, a O(n^2) solution would not run in time.

Comment: What do you mean unable to put it together? Maximum segment tree sounds good. You go down the tree while the max in the interval is greater or equal to k

Comment: If there are no updates, you can also probably use sparse table: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/range-minimum-query-for-static-array/

Comment: There are updates.  Yeah, maximum segment tree probably should work but I don’t know how I’d  implement it. Can you help me out? I think it should be a recursive tree, but moving down, I dunno how I’d write that.

Comment: In what language?

Comment: In c plus plus 14

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't teach you how to implement a segtree from scratch here on SO. You should look up some resources that do teach you this and try to implement it yourself. If you encounter any problems in the process, you can then ask a question here with the code which you've tried.

Comment: I know how to implement a segtree. I’m just unable to implement this function which would go down the tree ( as Juvian mentioned in the first comment ) and work in O(logn) per query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First build a max segment tree. This can be done in `O(nlogn)`. This will give us a function `get_max(l, r)` which gives the max number between indices `l` and `r` in `O(logn)`.
Let's call the desired query function `query(l, r, k)`. The original array is `arr`.

```
query(l, r, k) {
    if(l == r) {
        if(arr[l] >= k) {
            return l;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else {
        int mid = (l + r) / 2;
        if(get_max(l, mid) >= k) {
            return query(l, mid, k);
        }
        else {
            return query(mid + 1, r, k);
        }
    }
}
```

This should take [image] time per query.

Comment: Thanks you for this! But I was wondering if it can be done even faster by somehow just ‘descending’ down the tree or something? It seems plausible.

Comment: I think this might be very difficult since k is a variable here although I am not 100% sure. Your original objective of running under one second will be achieved with my algorithm as well.